# Data frame columns do not change once placing for-loop inside of function body - Rstudio

Tags: r, string, function, for-loop

I have a dataframe with many variables and I'd like to change their names using a function. The column names have the following form

```
"Department_Home_Converted_Sum"                  
"Department_Womenswear_Converted_Sum"               
"Department_Menswear_Converted_Sum"               
"Department_Shoes_Converted_Sum"               
"Department_Kidswear_Converted_Sum"
```

So I want to remove `"Department_"` and `"_Converted_Sum"`. I managed to to it just by looping through the column names like this which works fine.

```
for (i in seq(1,length(colnames(mydf)))){
    colnames(mydf)[i] = str_sub(colnames(mydf)[i], 11, str_length(colnames(mydf)[i])-14)
}
```

But what bothers me is that once I place this inside of a function and then use the function on `mydf`, the dataframe has no changed column names.

```
rename_columns <- function(df){
   for (i in seq(1,length(colnames(df)))){
      colnames(df)[i] = str_sub(colnames(df)[i], 11, str_length(colnames(df)[i])-14)
   }
}

rename_columns(mydf)
```

I also tried to add a `return(df)` but it did not help. Does any one know why the function can't mutate the column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is want to remove "Department_" and "_Converted_Sum" you can avoid the looping by using `str_remove_all()` from the `stringr` package.

```r
names(df) <- stringr::str_remove_all(names(df), "Department_|_Converted_Sum")
```

Comment: Only "Department_" is being removed using the above.

Comment: Fixed that in the code above. Meant to use `str_remove_all()`.